# 80 Gb file - Creating a data frame that submits data based upon a list of counties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am working with an 80 Gb data set in Python. The data has 30 columns and ~180,000,000 rows.

I am using the chunk size parameter in `pd.read_csv` to read the data in chunks where I then iterate through the data to create a dictionary of the counties with their associated frequency.

This is where I am stuck. Once I have the list of counties, I want to iterate through the chunks row-by-row again summing the values of 2 - 3 other columns associated with each county and place it into a new DataFrame. This would roughly be 4 cols and 3000 rows which is more manageable for my computer.

I really don't know how to do this, this is my first time working with a large data set in python.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df_chunk = pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t', chunksize=8000000)
county_dict = defaultdict(int)

for chunk in df_chunk:
    for county in chunk['COUNTY']:
        county_dict[county] += 1

for chunk in df_chunk:
    for row in chunk:
    # I don't know where to go from here
```

I expect to be able to make a DataFrame with a column of all the counties, a column for total sales of product "1" per county, another column for sales of product per county, and then more columns of the same as needed.

Comment: Why don't you use the `pyspark` package? It can handle such large datasets much better than `pandas`. `county_frequency = df.groupby("COUNTY").count()` will give you the frequency in a very optimal way. Here `df` is a `pyspark DataFrame`

Comment: You can also try the dask dataframe package. Here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The idea

I was not sure whether you have data for different **counties** (e.g. in UK or USA)
or **countries** (in the world), so I decided to have data concerning **countries**.

The idea is to:

- Group data from each chunk by country.
- Generate a partial result for this chunk, as a *DataFrame* with:

  - Sums of each column of interest (per country).
  - Number of rows per country.
- To perform concatenation of partial results (in a moment), each partial
  result should contain the chunk number, as an additional index level.
- Concatenate partial results vertically (due to the additional index level,
  each row has different index).
- The final result (total sums and row counts) can be computed as
  sum of the above result, grouped by country (discarding the chunk
  number).

## Test data

The source CSV file contains country names and 2 columns to sum (*Tab* separated):

```
Country Amount_1    Amount_2
Austria 41  46
Belgium 30  50
Austria 45  44
Denmark 31  42
Finland 42  32
Austria 10  12
France  74  54
Germany 81  65
France  40  20
Italy   54  42
France  51  16
Norway  14  33
Italy   12  33
France  21  30
```

For the test purpose I assumed chunk size of just **5** rows:

```
chunksize = 5
```

## Solution

The main processing loop (and preparatory steps) are as follows:

```
df_chunk = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', sep='\t', chunksize=chunksize)
chunkPartRes = []   # Partial results from each chunk
chunkNo = 0
for chunk in df_chunk:
    chunkNo += 1
    gr = chunk.groupby('Country')
    # Sum the desired columns and size of each group
    res = gr.agg(Amount_1=('Amount_1', sum), Amount_2=('Amount_2', sum))\
        .join(gr.size().rename('Count'))
    # Add top index level (chunk No), then append
    chunkPartRes.append(pd.concat([res], keys=[chunkNo], names=['ChunkNo']))
```

To concatenate the above partial results into a single *DataFrame*,
but still with separate results from each chunk, run:

```
chunkRes = pd.concat(chunkPartRes)
```

For my test data, the result is:

```
                 Amount_1  Amount_2  Count
ChunkNo Country                           
1       Austria        86        90      2
        Belgium        30        50      1
        Denmark        31        42      1
        Finland        42        32      1
2       Austria        10        12      1
        France        114        74      2
        Germany        81        65      1
        Italy          54        42      1
3       France         72        46      2
        Italy          12        33      1
        Norway         14        33      1
```

And to generate the final result, summing data from all chunks,
but keeping separation by countries, run:

```
res = chunkRes.groupby(level=1).sum()
```

The result is:

```
         Amount_1  Amount_2  Count
Country                           
Austria        96       102      3
Belgium        30        50      1
Denmark        31        42      1
Finland        42        32      1
France        186       120      4
Germany        81        65      1
Italy          66        75      2
Norway         14        33      1
```

## To sum up

Even if we look only on how numbers of rows per country are computed,
this solution is more "pandasonic" and elegant, than usage of *defaultdict*
and incrementation in a loop processing each row.

Grouping and counting of rows per group works significantly quicker
than a loop operating on rows.